# Convert millimeter to em

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, unit-conversion

I want to create an arial `System.Drawing.Font` with the font size of 5.9 millimeter. The font constructor allows the font size only in em:

> public Font(string familyName, **float emSize**, FontStyle style);

How can I convert millimeter to em? The dpi is 96.

Comment: new Font("Arial", 5.9f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a variable conversionFactor

```
var conversionFactor = 1/(4.2175176);
```

And before passing value to Constructor you need to multiply `conversionfactor` with `fontsize`

In this way:

> (fontsize) in mm * (conversionFactor) = (FontSize) in em

For 5.9 mm its

```
float emSize = conversionFactor*5.9
```